# CSS Textarea Not Filling Parent

Tags: c#, css, razor, flexbox

I am having issues getting a text area to fill a parent div. I have found solutions involving setting the box-sizing to border-box, but this is not working for me. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
             <div class="flx-modal">
                <div class="flx-label">
                    <label for="CorrectiveActionSteps">Time Line:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="flx-txtarea">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.TimeLine, new { @class = "form-control textarea" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

css:

```
.flx-modal{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

div.flx-txtarea {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0;
}

.flx-txtarea > textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* <=iOS4, <= Android  2.3 */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Chrome, IE8, Opera, Safari 5.1*/
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important; /* FF1+ */
}
```

Comment: .flx-txtarea > textarea use margin: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `flex-direction: column`, change `flex: 1` to `width: 100%` and remove the `margin-left: 15px`, you get this

```css
.flx-modal{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
div.flx-txtarea {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.flx-txtarea > textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* <=iOS4, <= Android  2.3 */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important; /* FF1+ */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Chrome, IE8, Opera, Safari 5.1*/
}
```

```html
<div class="flx-modal">
  <div class="flx-label">
    <label for="CorrectiveActionSteps">Time Line:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flx-txtarea">
    <textarea class="form-control textarea"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can also add `flex-wrap: wrap;`, remove `margin-left: 15px` and add this rule

```
div.flx-label {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.flx-modal{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
div.flx-label {
    width: 100%;
}
div.flx-txtarea {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0;
}
.flx-txtarea > textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* <=iOS4, <= Android  2.3 */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important; /* FF1+ */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Chrome, IE8, Opera, Safari 5.1*/
}
```

```html
<div class="flx-modal">
  <div class="flx-label">
    <label for="CorrectiveActionSteps">Time Line:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flx-txtarea">
    <textarea class="form-control textarea"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```